# 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'ContentView' what im missing?

Tags: swift, closures, swiftui

I'm try to running this code , but i'm getting the warning in the closure... any help to solve it?
In order to run a function filter in background thread i been suggest to run the init with the filter function.

But getting this warning in the closure:

'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'ContentView'

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager
    @State private var searchTerm : String = ""
    @State var filteredAirports: [AirportModel] = []
    init(dataM: DataManager) {
        self.dm = dataM
        dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector, closure: { [weak self] in
            self?.filteredAirports = $0 })
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)

            List {
                ForEach(filteredAirports) { valore in
                    Text(valore.aptICAO)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(dataM: DataManager())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`weak` is a modifier for reference types (ie. weak pointer, nullable when all references are released). But your `ContentView` is a `struct`, which is value type.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `[weak self]` as it used for refrence types like classes while `ContentView` is a value type `struct`

Comment: understood, problem is if I remove it I get warning  Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

Comment: @DamianoMiazzi Correct; you cannot mutate a struct this way. It's not quite clear what you're trying to do, but you likely want a Binding here rather than a callback. Views are just data that describe things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510620/why-cant-i-mutate-a-variable-initially-set-to-a-certain-parameter-when-the-func/59511421#59511421